# Laravel: abort_if vs throw_if

Tags: php, laravel, exception

As we know from the Laravel documentation, we can use [`abort_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-abort-if) to throw an HTTP exception if a given boolean expression evaluates to `true`, and [`throw_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-throw-if) to throw the given exception if a given boolean expression evaluates to `true`.

The example usages are given as follows:

```
abort_if(! Auth::user()->isAdmin(), 403);
throw_if(! Auth::user()->isAdmin(), AuthorizationException::class);
```

Since for the end user both methods will result in an exception, there seems to be no functional difference between them. Or does Laravel handle them differently in different configurations? In what situations would one choose to implement one over the other, or is it a matter of personal taste?

Comment: It is an exception. Laravel handles every exception on `Exceptions/Handler.php`. You can define your own resolutions in there, but `abort` will throw a special exception (can remember which one now), and the other one is your desired exception. There is no difference, only if you catch them on `Handler.php` and do something with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `abort_if` function can only throw an `HttpResponseException`, `NotFoundHttpException`, or `HttpException` exception, all of which are http response related. You will most typically see this used in the controller or a middleware, as these are most responsible for the http response.

The `throw_if` function allows you to specify the specific exception you'd like to throw, and isn't constrained to only http related exceptions. You will see this more in your application/business logic.